# Trouble installing keras with python 3.7.3

Tags: python, keras, windows-7

I am brand new to programming and python. I am having trouble installing keras for python 3.7.3. When I try to install keras it just return some very long error which I am not able to debug. I had a look on the keras webpage and it seems it has been released only for python 3.6 or lower?
Can anyone help me with this?
I am trying to run:

```
import keras as ks
```

Comment: Have you downloaded Keras before trying to import it on python? Open a command prompt (use the conda prompt if you are using Anaconda) and type:
`pip install keras`

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you actually show the error that you get

Comment: I did install it but trying to import it returns an error

Comment: Without complete error messages we cannot really help you.

Answer (score 2):

As of now (May 2019), Keras is NOT compatible with Python 3.7. Therefore, you must downgrade your python version to 3.6.

You can update when Keras support Python 3.7 on the following websites:

1. [Official Keras documentation](https://keras.io/)
2. [Keras Github issue for Python 3.7 support](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11690)